# Using Different layout Managers Not Working

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

I want to output the following layout
[image]

but my code instead outputs the following & I don't seem to understand why. I'm creating 4 Jpanels

1. Jpanel title to enclose the label --> BorderLayout
2. JPanel buttonPanel to enclose the 10x10 grid --> GridLayout
3. JPanel textPanel to enclose 3 textAreas --> Grid Layout 3x1
4. JPanel infoPanel to enclose 1 TextArea --> BorderLayout

then I'm adding each of the 4 JPanels to the JFrame as Border Layout, but that doesn't seem to work and I don't get why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setTitle("Alien Invasion");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel title = new JPanel();
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Invaded City");
    title.add(label1);
    frame.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10, 2, 2));
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Button" + (i + 1)));

    frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();
    textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 4, 4));


    JTextArea availableUnits = new JTextArea();
    availableUnits.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    availableUnits.setEditable(false);
    availableUnits.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
    availableUnits.setText("availableUnits\n ");
    availableUnits.setLineWrap(true);
    availableUnits.setWrapStyleWord(true); // words not broken up
    textPanel.add(availableUnits);

    JTextArea respondingUnits = new JTextArea();
    respondingUnits.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    respondingUnits.setEditable(false);
    respondingUnits.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
    respondingUnits.setText("respondingUnits\n ");
    respondingUnits.setLineWrap(true);
    respondingUnits.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textPanel.add(respondingUnits);

    JTextArea treatingUnits = new JTextArea();
    treatingUnits.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    treatingUnits.setEditable(false);
    treatingUnits.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
    treatingUnits.setText("treatingUnits\n ");
    treatingUnits.setLineWrap(true);
    treatingUnits.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textPanel.add(treatingUnits);

    frame.add(textPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    JPanel infoPanel = new JPanel();

    JTextArea informationDisplay = new JTextArea();
    informationDisplay.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), 200));
    informationDisplay.setEditable(false);
    informationDisplay.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));
    informationDisplay.setText("informationDisplay\n ");
    informationDisplay.setLineWrap(true);
    informationDisplay.setWrapStyleWord(true);

    infoPanel.add(informationDisplay);
    frame.add(infoPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor you're using for some of your JTextArea is:

```
JTextArea(int rows, int columns)
```

So you're creating them with 200 rows, that's a lot. Use JtextArea() instead.

Comment: what I understand from what you're saying is that I should use the JtextArea() empty constructor then later use setPreferredSize with the dimensions I want. However, I edit the code, but it still isn't working. JtextArea() sets the dimensions to what exactly?

Comment: All of your calls to JtextArea(int, int) need to be replaced by JtextArea(). That constructor is to give a number of row/columns (i.e. letters), not a size/number of pixels.